# Castom ComboBox and lose binding

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm trying to write my own ComboBox and I ran into a problem.

```
public class TestComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCarProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedCar", typeof(string), typeof(TestComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedCarPropertyChanged));

    public TestComboBox()
    {
        this.Cars = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Select Car", "BMW", "Mersedes", "Audi" };

        this.ItemsSource = this.Cars;
        this.SelectedItem = this.Cars[0];
    }

    public string SelectedCar
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedCarProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SelectedCarProperty, value); }
    }

    public IList<string> Cars { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        this.SelectedCar = (string)SelectedItem;
    }

    private static void OnSelectedCarPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var car = (string)e.NewValue;
        var editor = (TestComboBox)source;

        editor.SelectedItem = car;
    }
}
```

When I try to install the default value, I lose the binding. If I commented this code, everything works fine.

```
this.SelectedItem = this.Cars[0];
```

How can I set the default value without losing binding to the VM

P.S [TestApp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qecg3lv8wj20tye/WpfApplication1.rar?dl=0)

Updating question:

```
<propgrid:PropertyGrid Margin="0,0,11,7">
    <propgrid:PropertyGrid.Items>
        <propgrid:PropertyGridCategoryItem DisplayName="Main">
                <propgrid:PropertyGridPropertyItem Value="{Binding Car, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                               DisplayName="Car">
                <propgrid:PropertyGridPropertyItem.ValueTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <wpfApplication1:TestComboBox SelectedCar="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type propgrid:IPropertyDataAccessor}}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </propgrid:PropertyGridPropertyItem.ValueTemplate>
            </propgrid:PropertyGridPropertyItem>
        </propgrid:PropertyGridCategoryItem>
    </propgrid:PropertyGrid.Items>
</propgrid:PropertyGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving Mode = TwoWay for the binding.

Updating answer:

Referring your code - set mode TwoWay at

```
Value="{Binding Car}"
```

too.

"Car" is bound to "Value" and "Value" is bound to "SelectedCar"

Comment: I use this binding <wpfApplication1:TestComboBox SelectedCar="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type propgrid:IPropertyDataAccessor}}}" />

Comment: Updated the question. I tried to bind using TwoWay but it did not help